# Handling PayPal error code 10626 (Transaction refused due to risk model)

Tags: paypal

We're occasionally seeing a successful authorization of a payment but then when we later capture it we get error code 10626 - Transaction refused due to risk model. Here's the link to the error code:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#dodirectpayment-10626

I have three questions:

1. Why are we able to authorize it in the first place?
2. Is contacting the customer really the only way to handle this error or is there something that we can update in our PayPal integration to handle this?
3. If so, what should the customer be asked to check or do?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that contacting your customer will just leave him scratching his head; his bank will have no record of having rejected a charge. I have seen that vendors sometimes have success with just waiting for a few hours and trying the charge again. If that doesn't work out, I would contact the customer and ask if he has a different payment method he can use, as the first one is being declind at the processor.

Comment: Agreed! Only one I have though. I would have just commented on the question, but my rep's not high enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and error as well.  It ended up the customer's bank had the extra 4 digits on the zipcode so for example 95070 was not authorized but 95070-6070 was authorized.  Crazy.  Manager had to call paypal to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any PayPal Fraud products added? If so, the settings of these Fraud product (Fraud Management Filters / Fraud Protection Service) can help you ease the grip. Very stringent settings do not allow a lot of payment to go through.