# Paypal sandbox payment fails due to risk model

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am using the Angelleye CodeIgniter Paypal library to do direct payments. This is the link to the github library https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter

I have tried several times to make payments. Sometimes, the card payments are successful. However, some of it will suddenly show a 'Transaction refused due to risk model' error. I have tried looking around for a solution and even Paypal says just ask the client to choose a different payment method.

Isn't that strange that they themselves don't know the solution to this issue?

Comment: Paypals own documentation says "_Note: Inform the customer that PayPal declined the transaction. Contact PayPal Customer Service._" and "_Note: Contact the buyer._" also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400566/handling-paypal-error-code-10626-transaction-refused-due-to-risk-model

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I have contacted them but how would I contact the buyer when its still in sandbox mode?

Comment: Please file a ticket to PayPal MTS at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ for this sandbox related declines. MTS team will help further.